# Swift FSCalendar Interactive Scope Gesture programmatically

Tags: swift, fscalendar

I'm using [FSCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FSCalendar) to create a calendar for my app but I can not get the `Interactive Scope Gesture` to work. I have downloaded the example project and read through the documentation but it still crashes with this error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` on line `calendarHeightConstraint.constant = 350`. All I'm trying to achieve is the exact same as the documentation shows with the [Interactive Scope Gesture](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FSCalendar#interactive-scope-gesture) but programmatically.

```
var calendarHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

let calendarView: FSCalendar = {
    let cl = FSCalendar()
    cl.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    return cl
}()

let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "backgroundColor")
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    return cv
}()

fileprivate lazy var scopeGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
    [unowned self] in
    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self.calendarView, action: #selector(self.calendarView.handleScopeGesture(_:)))
    panGesture.delegate = self
    panGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    panGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 2
    return panGesture
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "backgroundColor")
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    calendarView.delegate = self
    calendarView.dataSource = self
    
    calendarHeightConstraint.constant = 350

    self.calendarView.select(Date())
    
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.scopeGesture)
    self.calendarView.addGestureRecognizer(self.scopeGesture)
    self.calendarView.scope = .week
    
    setupLayout()
    setupCollectionView()
}

func setupLayout() {
    
    view.addSubview(calendarView)
    calendarView.anchor(top: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 75, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 350)

    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.anchor(top: calendarView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 15, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
}

func setupCollectionView() {
    
    collectionView.register(CalendarCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CalendarCollectionCell
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 70)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 15
}

func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, boundingRectWillChange bounds: CGRect, animated: Bool) {
    self.calendarHeightConstraint.constant = bounds.height
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by doing two things.

1. Remove the line `calendarHeightConstraint.constant = 350` from `viewDidLoad`.
2. Initialize the `calendarHeightConstraint` in `setupLayout`.

Instead of:

```
calendarView.anchor(top: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 75, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 350)
```

Use:

```
calendarView.anchor(top: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 75, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 0)
calendarHeightConstraint = calendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350)
calendarHeightConstraint.isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't init

```
 var calendarHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

or link it as an outlet hence it's nil , you need to link it here

```
calendarView.anchor(top: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 75, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 350)
```

so you can play with it's `constant` as needed , so you can do

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   // add left , right and top constraints
])
```

in addition to

```
calendarHeightConstraint = calendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 350)
calendarHeightConstraint.isActive = true
```

Don't try to use `calendarHeightConstraint`  before the above 2 lines as this will give the nil crash